# Encrypt file using PGP in python throws error, PGPError: Key 169ADF2575FB does not have the required usage flag EncryptStorage, EncryptCommunications

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pgp, openpgp

I am trying to encrypt file using pgp module but the public which I am using is throwing flag error.I tried to follow documentation [here](https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html), and I tried to generate a new key but it's only generating private key as mentioned in document **Generating Primary Keys**, But we need pair of public and private keys to encrypt and decrypt right? rest of it mentioned in document I am not able to understand(signing and verifying things)

```
from pgpy import PGPKey, PGPMessage
pub_key, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file('PublicPGP1.asc')
#pub_key._require_usage_flags = False 'This feature have been removed'
with io.open('test.csv', "r",newline='') as csv_file:
    input_data = csv_file.read()
msg = pgpy.PGPMessage.new(input_data)
encrypted_message = pub_key.encrypt(msg)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raia6\Desktop\pgpy\pgpenc.py", line 19, in <module>
    encrypted_phrase = key.encrypt(message)
  File "C:\Users\raia6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pgpy\decorators.py", line 125, in _action
    with self.usage(key, kwargs.get('user', None)) as _key:
  File "C:\Users\raia6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\raia6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pgpy\decorators.py", line 96, in usage
    raise PGPError("Key {keyid:s} does not have the required usage flag {flags:s}".format(**em))
pgpy.errors.PGPError: Key 35AF67D132D325C9 does not have the required usage flag EncryptStorage, EncryptCommunications
```

My requirement is to generate public and private key (with flag), and then encrypt and decrypt data.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must not use private key for encryption. Export it's public part, and use it instead. Private key is used for decryption and should be kept secret.
2. In PGP keys and subkeys have some flags, telling for which purpose it may be used. In your case generated primary key seems to be sign-only, so you should generate encrypting subkey and add it to the primary key.

See RFC 4880 for more details on OpenPGP keys/protocol.
To check your key parameters you may use `gpg --list-packets PublicPGP1.asc` or `rnp --list-packets PublicPGP1.asc` if you have the later one built/installed.